# Why can't I change the color of NavigationBar in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

I am simply trying to get a top bar that displays the name of the viewController and a button on the right that says "Log Out". Currently I am struggling with even changing the color of the navBar. This is the code I have and I am curious why it doesn't seem to work.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
```

I've tried this code:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 100, green: 186, blue: 44, alpha: 1)
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

I've also tried using, `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .red` but it doesn't work either.

All I get is a dark black navBar with no text. Can someone explain to me why this code doesn't seem to work?

Following is my implementation of the code suggested by stoikokolev which doesn't seem to work for me:

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
        
appearance.shadowColor = .clear
appearance.shadowImage = nil
appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 100.0/255.0, green: 186.0/255.0, blue: 44.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .black
UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance

if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().compactScrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use this code snippet in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in the AppDelegate:

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: yourTextColor,
                                  .font: yourFont]
appearance.shadowColor = .clear
appearance.shadowImage = nil
appearance.backgroundColor = yourBackgroundColor
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = yourTintColor
UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().compactScrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
}
```

Comment: I added the code you suggested and it doesn't appear to have worked. I can't see any navBar at all anymore. I will add the code I applied to my question.